# JS if else statement and a reset

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent any actions if the button attack is not clicked. In this case i want to prevent If attack is clicked you can click on send troops, else alert('You need first to attack!'). Also when the time runs out, i want to the clock disappear if that is possible.

Clock

```
   <button class="attack" onclick="startTimer(60,document.querySelector('#time'))">ATTACK</button>
<button class="troops" onclick="send()">SEND TROOPS</button>
```

JS

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,minutes, seconds;
  var timers = setInterval(runner, 1000);
  function runner() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer <= 0) {
     clearInterval(timers)
     finish()
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: this kind of has a homework vibe to it. The title says If else and a reset, but I am not seeing an else statement or a reset.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Im asking not for you to do, just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can add "disabled" attribute to "SEND TROOPS" button at first, it will disable this button which will prevent clicking it. 
you can remove that attribute when "ATTACK" is clicked.

Add attribute

```
document.getElementsByClassName("troops")[0]).setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
```

Remove attribute:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("troops")[0]).removeAttribute("disabled","disabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global flag (say `isAttacked`) which will store whether the attacked button is clicked. Then in the `send` function check for `isAttacked` variable and if it's `true` send the troops.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {

  // Make troops button enabled when attack button is clicked
  document.getElementsByClassName("troops")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");

  var timer = duration,minutes, seconds;
  var timers = setInterval(runner, 1000);
  function runner() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer <= 0) {
     clearInterval(timers)
     finish()
   }
 }

}
```

```html
<button class="attack" onclick="startTimer(60,document.querySelector('#time'))">ATTACK</button>

<!-- declare troops button disabled before attack has been clicked -->
<button class="troops" disabled onclick="send()">SEND TROOPS</button>
```